# GNU make 3.81: eval function not working?

Tags: makefile, eval

I recently found this piece of example code from the GNU make documentation that refers to the eval function. I really like it, but when I tried to test it on my machine (make 3.81/Debian), all it does is trying to link the server without compiling the c files first ... why? Is make 3.81 not compatible?

Shell output:

```
$ make
cc     -o server
cc: no input files
```

Code:

```
 PROGRAMS    = server client

 server_OBJS = server.o server_priv.o server_access.o
 server_LIBS = priv protocol

 client_OBJS = client.o client_api.o client_mem.o
 client_LIBS = protocol

 # Everything after this is generic

 .PHONY: all
 all: $(PROGRAMS)

 define PROGRAM_template =
  $(1): $$($(1)_OBJS) $$($(1)_LIBS:%=-l%)
  ALL_OBJS   += $$($(1)_OBJS)
 endef

 $(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))

 $(PROGRAMS):
         $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

 clean:
         rm -f $(ALL_OBJS) $(PROGRAMS)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it will work if you remove the `=` from the `define` line:

```
define PROGRAM_template
  ...
endef
```

I've tested this with GNUMake 3.81. As for *why* this works and the version in the manual doesn't, I have no idea.

Comment: The problem is that the `=` is a feature added in GNU make 3.82 and the GNU make manual (including the copy on gnu.org, where Google will send most people) doesn't give the slightest hint when a feature is specific to 3.82.  Compare http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/gnumake/make_3.html#SEC22 (3.81) with http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles (3.82)

Comment: Almost two years later and this is still an issue (in Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Another two years later and it's still an issue (OSX)

Comment: Ten years later and it’s still an issue (macOS).